# Replace number with asterisk mark in bash

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have the following number as example :

**123456789**

and I want to to replace from 4-8 with asterisk mark :

**123****89**

Comment: Your example only replaces 4-7. That aside, do you want to replace these numbers wherever they occur (1247961 -> 12**9*1)? Or do you want to replace the 4th through 7th (8th?) characters in any string with **** ?

Comment: Are these input by the user? Are they in a file? In a variable?

Comment: Bash and other shells have methods to manipulate variable values; otherwise we’re talking about text processing tools.

Answer (score 3):

To replace exactly the string `4567` use:

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) `echo '123456789' | sed 's/4567/****/'`
[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) `echo '123456789' | awk 'gsub("4567","****",$0)'`

To replace any number in range `4-7` anywhere they appear use:

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) `echo '123456789' | sed 's/[4567]/*/g'`
[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) `echo '123456789' | awk 'gsub(/[4567]/,"*",$0)'`

Answer (score 1):

To substitute a range of characters from the position 4 to 8(excluding):

```
sed -E 's/(...).{4}/\1****/' <<<"123456789" 
123****89
```

---

- `(...)` - the first 3 chars captured into the 1st parenthesized group
- `.{4}` - the next 4 characters to be substituted/replaced

Answer (score 1):

Since were talking about Bash, you'll likely want to use just the different operators available with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

Do you want to replace the string `4567` with `****`?

```
$ var=abcdefghi123456789
$ echo "${var/4567/****}"
abcdefghi123****89
```

Or any of the numbers `4` to `7` with asterisks?

```
$ var=-3-4-5-6-7-8-
$ echo "${var//[4-7]/*}"
-3-*-*-*-*-8-
```

Or the 4th to 7th characters, whatever they are?

```
$ var=abcdäöäö
$ echo "${var:0:3}****${var:7}"
abc****ö
```

Note that neither of those, the substring expansion `${var:n:m}` or the replacement `${var:pattern:repl}` is a POSIX feature, but they're supported by most shells.

Answer (score 0):

These 3 methods work:

1. ```
   echo "123456789" | sed "s/\(...\)\(....\)/\1\****/g"
   ```
2. ```
   echo "123456789" | sed "s/\(...\)\([0-9]\{5\}\)/\1\****/g"
   ```
3. ```
   echo "123456789" | sed "s/[^12389]/*/g"
   ```

Output

```
123****89
```